# OpenAL issue, undefined reference to '_imp__alGenBuffers'

Tags: c++, audio, openal

I finally decided to download OpenAL, and OpenALUT. Upon writing my first bit of code, I came across a slight issue. Everytime I compile, I get the error listed in the title. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Code listed below, thanks.
PS: I am using Code::Blocks.

```
#include <AL/al.h>
#include <AL/alut.h>

#define NUM_BUFFERS 1

int main()
{

    ALuint buffers[ NUM_BUFFERS ];

    alGenBuffers( NUM_BUFFERS, buffers );

}
```

I don't expect a real result out of this, I just expect that it compiles. I'm fairly certain it's an issue with my installation of OpenAL, although I am sure I did everything correctly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was my fault, I didn't link the libraries correctly. If you are having this error, then make sure you have linked them correctly, and/or they are the correct bit type, compared to the rest of the files.

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on how you liked them before/after. Trying to build mingw-w64-freealut and failing at similar errors.

Comment: You could have told how you solved the problem. I'm having the same issue and don't know what to do.

Comment: Sorry, thought this would be enough info. How are you building your project? Make? Visual Studio? If you're getting these issues, it's because you're successfully including the headers, so your code and the compiler knows what functions you're trying to call, but during link time it cannot find the actual definitions of the functions.

This issue will always be solved by properly linking your libraries, and that process always changes depending on what build system you're using.